# Converting Seconds Into user friendly format using php

Tags: php

I have a large number in seconds that I'm looking to convert into a result for example;

[image: Example]

But that value is stored in seconds `1728000`.

This is my current code but nothing is returned. As you can see I'm trying to make it as Human-Like as possible.

```
function convert_seconds($seconds)
 {
    if ($seconds <= 60){
      return "nill";
    } else if ($seconds >= 60 || $seconds <= 3600){ # hr
      $time = ($seconds) / 3600;
      $time_val = "Hour";
    } else if ($seconds >= 3600 || $seconds <= 86400){ # day
      $time = 0;
      $time = ($seconds) / 86400;
      $time_val = "Day";
    } else if ($seconds >= 86400 || $seconds <= 604800){ # week
      $time = 0;
      $time = ($seconds) / 604800;
      $time_val = "Week";
    }

    if ($time_val == "Hour" || $time <= 120){
      $time_val == "Hours";
    } else if ($time_val == "Day" || $time <= 7200){
      $time_val == "Days";
    } else if ($time_val == "Week" || $time <= 172800){
      $time_val == "Weeks";
    }
  return $time.' '.$time_val;
  }
echo convert_seconds(1728000);
```

The code isn't presise enough, for example 60 seconds will return `0.0169444444444 Hours`?? If anyone knows a better way I would love to hear.

Comment: Your function is missing `return "$time $time_val";`

Comment: @Nick I have modified the question

Comment: @CharlieSimon i checked your code and it return 480 hour ?? your code is working fine

Comment: @ProblemSolver I was using an example -> "for example 60 seconds will return 0.0169444444444 Hours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. Firstly you need to use `&&`, not `||` in the conditions, otherwise your second condition is always true. Also, your conditions are such that `$time` will always be 0 or 1 since you are dividing by the biggest value it can be for that condition. Try this instead:

```
function convert_seconds($seconds) {
    if ($seconds < 60){
      return "nill\n";
    } 
    else if ($seconds >= 60 && $seconds < 3600){ # hr
      $time = floor($seconds / 60);
      $time_val = "Minute";
    }
    else if ($seconds >= 3600 && $seconds < 86400){ # day
      $time = floor($seconds / 3600);
      $time_val = "Hour";
    }
    else if ($seconds >= 86400 && $seconds < 604800){ # week
      $time = floor($seconds / 86400);
      $time_val = "Day";
    }
    else if ($seconds >= 604800) {
        $time = floor($seconds / 604800);
        $time_val = "Week";
    }
    if ($time > 1) $time_val .= 's';
     return "$time $time_val\n";
}
echo convert_seconds(40);
echo convert_seconds(530);
echo convert_seconds(35930);
echo convert_seconds(240000);
echo convert_seconds(2345775);
```

Output:

```
nill 
8 Minutes 
9 Hours 
2 Days 
3 Weeks
```

I've assumed you want integer output, if you want decimal (e.g. `8.25 Hours`), you can change the `floor` to an appropriate `round` e.g. `$time = round($seconds / 60, 2);`

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FSSC4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a return statement. You also should use a single "=" to assign a variable.

```
    function convert_seconds($seconds)
 {
    if ($seconds <= 60){
      return "nill";
    } else if ($seconds >= 60 || $seconds <= 3600){ # hr
      $time = ($seconds) / 3600;
      $time_val = "Hour";
    } else if ($seconds >= 3600 || $seconds <= 86400){ # day
      $time = 0;
      $time = ($seconds) / 86400;
      $time_val = "Day";
    } else if ($seconds >= 86400 || $seconds <= 604800){ # week
      $time = 0;
      $time = ($seconds) / 604800;
      $time_val = "Week";
    }

    if ($time_val == "Hour" || $time <= 120){
      $time_val = "Hours";
    } else if ($time_val == "Day" || $time <= 7200){
      $time_val = "Days";
    } else if ($time_val == "Week" || $time <= 172800){
      $time_val = "Weeks";
    }

     return $time.' '.$time_val;
  }
```